# how to run cut command using single tick as a delimiter?

Tags: macos, shell, cut

I'm on MAC 10.9.2 and trying to take out some data from the sql file.

it has portions of CSV values wrapped in single ticks ('), and I would like to take out field 5

here is what I have so far, and for some reason I get > at the end, like asking me to complete action, but what I expect is to get results?

```
sh-3.2# more data.sql | cut -d ',' -s -f 5 | cut -d '\'' -f 1
>
```

maybe there is an easier solution that cutting? :)

Comment: Give some sample input and your expected output.

Comment: If the single quotes are intended to protect commas from being treated as field delimiters, you're going to want to use a language that has an actual CSV parser, rather than trying to use `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using attempting to escape the single quote within single quotes.  Use a different pair of enclosing quotes without escaping, or eliminate the quotes altogether, i.e. either:

```
cut -d\' -f2
```

or

```
cut -d"'" -f2
```

(An alternate solution might be available given the sample data.)